# How to create a json that conforms to AVRO schema?

Tags: json, avro

The service gets a json response from another service, need to create another json that conforms to an AVRO schema based on received response. How can this be implemented?

Comment: you can use the same schema and read the classes in your consumer.

Comment: For more details please refer to my Kafka-producer and consumer example where i use AVRO Below are the links.

https://github.com/naveenkulkarni029/kafka-producer

https://github.com/naveenkulkarni029/kafka-consumer

Comment: using generated classes, this can be achieved. Is there a dynamic/more flexible approach available? The json received contains just one section of the data required for the json that needs to be built. The json that requires to be built has more sections.

Comment: Well you can add the avro build classes during maven install

Comment: Then you don't need to create objects maven will create you the classes during maven install